# Typeerror: require is not a consructo

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: ошибка]

```js
var vk = new (require('vk-io')); 
^ 

TypeError: require(...) is not a constructor 
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\system32\b 
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) 
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js: 
at Module.load (module.js:565:32) 
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12) 
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10 
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16) 
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3 
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5) 
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)\
```

Вылазит эта ошибка при запуске бота.

Comment: убери `new` тут `var vk = new (require('vk-io'));`

Comment: Тогда ругается, что 
vk.setToken<TOKEN>is not a function

Comment: полагаю тебе нужно что-то вроде: `var VK = require('vk-io'); var vk= new VK(/*тут возможно параметры*/);`